# Why does git delete commited files on the server after committing and pushing from a client computer?

Tags: git, github

I have setup git on my server (desktop computer) and on my laptop. I cloned the remote repository with is sitting on my server and I added new files. I then push the committed however when I perform the git command "git status" on the server, all the file are deleted.

Comment: So you say you're executing `git pull; git add {somefiles}; git commit; git push` and then files are deleted in your folder?

Comment: Git normal prevents you from pushing to a checked out branch, have you changed the `receive.denyCurrentBranch` config setting?

Comment: `git status` doesn't report on all files, only the ones that have changed since the last commit.

Comment: @syntonym, the files got deleted on the server. @Charles Bailey I changed it to `receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore`.

Comment: I have actually set the `receive.denyCurrentBranch` to false and it worked. Thanks for your time and effort guys.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed it using `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch false`.